# REST API failure - org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement

Tags: mysql, jpa, h2, jpql

I'm working on a Java EE 7 project that connects to a MySQL database. When I try to make any API calls via Swagger Inspector (while the server is running and the .war is deployed, of course), I get the below errors:

`org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement`

and

```
`Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "APARTMENTS" not found; SQL statement:
select apartment0_.id as id1_0_, apartment0_.apt as apt2_0_, apartment0_.city as city3_0_, apartment0_.country as country4_0_, apartment0_.numberOfBedrooms as numberOf5_0_, apartment0_.postalCode as postalCo6_0_, apartment0_.state as state7_0_, apartment0_.street as street8_0_ from apartments apartment0_ order by apartment0_.postalCode [42102-197]`
```

The things that stand out to me are that, first, I'm not using Hibernate to my knowledge. Pretty sure I'm using JPQL. Second, I'm not trying to connect to a H2 database. So why would I get errors related to technology I'm not using?

I'm using Intellij and was able to add the correct MySQL DB within the IDE.

Here's an example of one of the SQL query methods, in case I really am somehow using incorrect syntax:

> public List findAll() {
> TypedQuery query = em.createQuery("SELECT a from Apartment a order by a.postalCode",Apartment.class);
> return query.getResultList();
> }`

Pretty lost and confused, and new to this, so any help would be appreciated!

Edit (8/11/21 5:11PM CST) to add persistence.xml:

```
`  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd"
                 version="3.0">
        <persistence-unit name="rentRantPU">
        <class>com.rentRant.rentRant.model.Apartment</class>
            <class>com.rentRant.rentRant.model.User</class>
            <class>com.rentRant.rentRant.model.Review</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/rentRant"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="****"/>
        </properties>
      </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>`
```

Comment: Always provide runtime information with versions. What application server are you running? Hibernate is a JPA (Java Persistance Api) implementation. So, if you are running on e.g. WildFly, which has Hibernate as standard JPA provider, you are using Hibernate without your knowlege. Also, JPQL (Java Persistence Query Langauge) is not comparable to Hibernate. It is the query language used with JPA. If you are running on e.g. WildFly, it comes with a default example H2 datasource, that you are maybe incorrectly connecting to as result of some misconfiguration. Can you provide your persistence.xml?

Comment: You were right about my using Wildfly (version 24.0.0.Final). I didn't realize it used Hibernate under the hood. I edited my initial post to include the persistence xml information. Thanks for the reply!